# Is it a norm or not? Checking by 3 axioms.

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, proof-verification, normed-spaces

**Task:**

On the set $C^2[a, b] := \lbrace f: [a, b]\to R \text{ are twice continuous differentiable function} \rbrace$

are defined functions $F_i :C^2[a, b]\to R, i \in\{ 1, 2, 3\}$. We have 3 specific functions:

$$F_1(f)=\max_{a\le t\le b} |f(t)|$$ $$F_2(f)=\max_{a\le t\le b} |f'(t)|$$ $$F_3(f)=\max_{a\le t\le b} |f''(t)|$$

**Is it a norm of $C^2[a, b]$:**

(a) $\Vert f\Vert =\vert f(b)-f(a)\vert  + F_2(f) + F_3(f)$

(b) $\Vert f\Vert =\vert f(b)\vert+\vert f(a)\vert + F_3(f)$

(c) $\Vert f\Vert = \int_{a}^ b \vert f(t)\vert dt   + F_3(f)$

**My solution for (a) is:**

I need to check 3 axioms:

1) $\Vert f\Vert  \ge 0$. (it is true because of absolute values) and

$\Vert f\Vert  = 0 \iff f=0$ (*here I have some problems to show it is true*).

2) $\Vert \mathcal L f\Vert = \vert\mathcal L \vert \Vert f \Vert$

Proof:

\begin{align*}
\Vert \mathcal L f\Vert & = \vert\mathcal L f(b) - \mathcal L f(a) \vert + F_2(\mathcal L f) + F_3(\mathcal L f)\\
& = \vert\mathcal L (f(b) - f(a)) \vert + \mathcal L F_2(f) + \mathcal L F_3(f) \\
&= \vert \mathcal L \vert ( \vert (f(b) - f(a)) \vert + F_2(f) + F_3(f)) \\
&= \vert\mathcal L \vert \Vert f \Vert
\end{align*}

So it is true.

3) $\Vert  f+ g \Vert \le \vert f \vert + \vert g \vert$.

True, because of $ F_2(f+g) \le F_2(f) + F_2(g)$.

**Question:**
The same I did with (b) and (c) and my result is that all of them are norms. Is my proof correct? What about (b) and (c)? Maybe I cannot notice something and make mistake? It looks for my strange that I got 3 norms here.

Comment: For (a), the condition that $\left| \left| f \right| \right| = 0 \Leftrightarrow f = 0$ cannot be satisfied. Infact, it is satisfied for any constant function $f: \left[ a, b \right] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I am sure I have seen an extremely similar question yesterday ...

Comment: A comment on notation, but I don't think it's common to use $\mathcal{L}$ to denote a scalar. More common is $\lambda, \mu, k,$ etc and while $\mathcal{L}$ is technically okay, you should define it to prevent confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keypoint is the condition $$\|f\|=0\Rightarrow f=0.$$
Since all the proposed candidates for norms contain the term $F_3(f)$, from 
$$\|f\|_i\Rightarrow0$$
follows that $f$ is linear, i.e. $f(x)=kx+d$ for some constants $k,d$.
Now for $\|\cdot\|_b,\|\cdot\|_c$ this leads to $f=0$, since a linear function with two zeros is zeros, and also it is easy to check that
$$\int_a^b|kx+d|\,dx=0\Rightarrow k,d=0.$$

For $\|\cdot\|_a$ on the other hand as @Aniruddha Deshmukh pointed out in the comments
for any function $f(x)=c$ we have
$$\|f\|_a=|f(a)-f(b)|+F_2(f)+F_3(f)=0.$$